# Same Admob ad unit ID for different apps?

Tags: android, admob

**Context**

We are trying to integrate `admob` inside our Apps, we have 25 apps which are mainly livewallpapers.

When we created an ad unit ID inside `admob`, we provided app name as one of our own app package name inside the playstore.

We have two activities, and we have used two banner ad unit ID for each of the activity.

**Questions**

- 1. Can we use these two unit ID inside our 25 apps, Two unit IDs are assigned under one package name inside `admob` console
- 2. Having two banner ID inside same activiy will increase the impression or will it count as just one? or if we want to add two banner ad inside same activity, we have to use different ID for different banner ID?

Comment: Same situation for me lol. I just hope my account doesn't get banned for using the same ad unit id in multiple apps :P. I don't care about statistics in this certain case lol.

Answer (score 8):

I can only partly answer your questions:
You can use one unit ID (which is assigned to any of your apps) in all your apps. But in my opinion, this is a very bad idea. Why. Because it produces fake statistics (the one app listed in AdMob shows all advertisting statistics of all apps). In the end, you will not even see how to optimize your earnings because you don't know which app causes lots of earnings and which one does not. (e.g. If one apps causes no earnings you could place your ad somewhere else within the app). So one unit id per app would be a good solution.

I can't answer question 2, because I never thought about something and I suggest to reconsider your intention because too much ads will annoy the user and you will not earn more because the user will surely not click twice just because you use two banners. He probably won't click because it annoys him. And I'm not even sure if there are different ads showing at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, In my case its 25 livewallpapers, and i dont want much of statistics, and there is part of activity which is shared by all 25 livewallpapers, so for me its more convenient to update a single ad unit ID and export all 25 apps. Regarding second one, i think i read somewhere its only allowed to use one ad at a time on one screen, or it should be in another corner of the screen.And yeah i dont want to annoy the user, I just want a fast method to implement admob in all apps.

Comment: @unitedartinc If I understand you right, the only additional work you have to is to create the unit IDs for every app in AdMob console. In any case you have to add the unit ID in your app, so why not creating a new one for each app.

Comment: But admob is integrated in that common code part, so each time when i export the app, I need to change the unit ID, Sorry if i sound too lazy XD Also i dont want any statistics for each app since one of my app is getting the main downloads and others are just secondary, their downloads are kind of bonus to the actual one.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Go to Monetize (on top) -> Filter -> add App & ad unit -> Select ad unit -> [select your ad unit] -> Apply

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple ad units are not recommended as it will lead to incorrect statistics on your app usage and user engagement. So, it's better to use different ad units for different activities and for the second part of the question having multiple ad-banners in a single activity is against the google admob guidelines. Using a same ad unit id or different does not affect your earning so if you're concerned with the revenue generated by ad units the you can use multiple ad units too.
Check this thread for more info: http://forums.makingmoneywithandroid.com/advertising-networks/34763-native-ads-banners-admob-policy.html