# Android testDeviceIds are they device specific or app specific?

Tags: android, admob, ads

After like 5 years, I am trying to again integrate the admob with my mobile apps, I am just confused by the documentation. As discussed here [Same Admob ad unit ID for different apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175948/same-admob-ad-unit-id-for-different-apps), We use same ad unit ID on all my 20 plus apps.

Following the documentation for testing the ads, this is what I understand that we cannot use "those apps in play store which give Device ID" anymore. Instead we have to manually get it from the logs using android studio. Even in that case, I see that my device shows different `testdeviceID` when I opened multiple apps in my mobile. So I am confused and I want to check with your expert opinion ahead of publishing the apps.

So below is my consolidated questions

1) There is no way to get the device ID with out connecting the android studio ? If I do and debug build, I can't send it to another guy to test it out ?

2) Are these test IDs device Specific or App specific ? Or is it a combination of both ?

3) Do we need to remove those test ID before publishing ? Is there any problem if I keep it ?

4) Old Device ID and this Test device IDs are different ?

Comment: leaving these ids into prod code will serve test ads so it is better if you remove them. you can check programmatically if the app is prod or debug build.

Comment: Another thing we have done is we have setup test campaigns with custom targeting setup on dfp server. this custom target is being sent only in debug/dev builds

Comment: @Ankit Leaving these ids in prod code will serve test ads only to the device with this ID right ? Rest all devices will receive actual ads right ? And this will also avoid unnecessary clicking by developers after its published.

Comment: Device IDs from one device are the same on different apps. Some cases in which the device ID changes: 1) factory reset 2) major version update. For your information.

Comment: @vegafish So its both app specific and device specific right ? So what if i use a common module for multiple apps ? Device test IDs will be different for debugging each applications right ?

Comment: @unitedartinc Device IDs from one device are the same on each app. For example,  device X has ID Y on the app P, device X also has ID Y on the app Q.

Comment: @vegafish So you mean to say Test deviceID stay same for all the apps, But thats not true, because if i enable logging on different application, i can see different IDs in the logs. ( As per documentation, this is how to capture the testdeviceID and i get different ID for different apps installed on my device ).

Comment: I am not sure if the test ads will be served in that. in our app we are not using this test id.